# Variations of the word "Schadenfreude"

Tags: vocabulary

*Schadenfreude* is pleasure derived from the misfortune of others.

Is there a word which means to take pleasure in the misfortune of another *when previously that misfortune was inflicted on you by that other person*?

I won't describe here (in public) the particular circumstances in which I find myself looking for such a word, instead please enjoy this example from [Three Men In A Boat](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/308/308-h/308-h.htm).

> Rather an amusing thing happened while
>   dressing that morning.  I was very
>   cold when I got back into the boat,
>   and, in my hurry to get my shirt on, I
>   accidentally jerked it into the water.
>   It made me awfully wild, especially as
>   George burst out laughing.  I could
>   not see anything to laugh at, and I
>   told George so, and he only laughed
>   the more.  I never saw a man laugh so
>   much.  I quite lost my temper with him
>   at last, and I pointed out to him what
>   a drivelling maniac of an imbecile
>   idiot he was; but he only roared the
>   louder.  And then, just as I was
>   landing the shirt, I noticed that it
>   was not my shirt at all, but George’s,
>   which I had mistaken for mine;
>   whereupon the humour of the thing
>   struck me for the first time, and I
>   began to laugh.  And the more I looked
>   from George’s wet shirt to George,
>   roaring with laughter, the more I was
>   amused, and I laughed so much that I
>   had to let the shirt fall back into
>   the water again.

Comment: Do you mean a word for pleasure derived from revenge?

Comment: @Bruno Almost, but in the quoted example no revenge is taken (until the shirt drops again)

Comment: `Schadenfreude` is a German word. It is used among English speakers mainly out of amusement that the Germans would bother to make a word for such a thing. If you are looking for similar words, you really should be asking German speakers (deutch.stackexchage.com ?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the most appropriate term for that situation is that one is feeling *revenged*.

Comment: Did you mean __avenged__? I've never heard of 'revenged' as the adjective.

Comment: @Mitch: No. *Avenged* has several inapplicable implications.  I don't know what to tell you about the fact that you haven't seen *revenged* in this usage other than "sooner or later you will".

Answer (score 8):

I can't think if a phrase for the feeling, but

- "just deserts" is used to describe
  what the other person is felt to
  receive; and
- "poetic justice" may
  describe the circumstances: the fact that they do
  receive their just deserts.

Comment: @Jasper Great point. Here I've always thought the derivation of the word was the same as *dessert* but evidently that word comes from the French *desservir* "to clear the table" whereas *desert* in the sense of punishment/reward comes from Old French *deservir* "to deserve"

Comment: @Jasper - yes, of course I did. Thank you. I'll edit it.

Comment: @Jasper: Amusingly, if you search Google for *just deserts*, it suggests "Did you mean: *just desserts*." This may be as much of a lost cause as *begging the question*.

Comment: @Jasper: you learn something new every day

Comment: _["Just deserts" or "just desserts"](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/26684/5822)_

Answer (score 4):

We have a Japanese popular saying, 'the other's agony (trouble) is my own pleasure,' which I think exactly fits to the word shadenfreude. We also have another Japanese proverb, 'Misfortune (unhappiness) of others tastes (sweet) like honey'.

Answer (score 2):

How about *gloat* or *gloating*?

Answer (score 2):

*Gloating* is nice, and variations on *malicious glee* always struck me as pretty.

Answer (score 0):

One word that is coming to me is *[spite](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spite)*.

> petty ill will or hatred with the disposition to irritate, annoy, or thwart

[MW]

Comment: Can you provide a link please, and make sure the quote from MW is exact.

Comment: @jimm101 https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spite