# Antonym for Schadenfreude used for the feeling of discomfort derived from witnessing the misfortunes of others

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

*Schadenfreude* is the joy or pleasure derived from the misfortunes of others. What is the word for the feeling of discomfort derived from witnessing the misfortunes of others?

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/11044/2085 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/61008/2085 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/49949/2085 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/79526/2085

Comment: Sounds a lot like *empathy* in a general sense. *Pity* or *angst* may apply. Wikipedia refers to it as "empathic distress".

Answer (score 7):

[*Compassion*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/compassion): "sympathetic consciousness of others' distress together with a desire to alleviate it".

Answer (score 6):

> [*Commiseration*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/commiseration): a feeling of sympathy and sorrow for the misfortunes of others

I think there is a subtle difference between *commiseration* and *compassion*, where *commiseration* involves actually feeling miserable along with the other person while *compassion* aims more toward the desire to alleviate it.

Comment: Good point. **Compassion**: _I feel your pain and I want to help you alleviate it_. **Commiseration**: _I feel your pain and have to cry about it as much as you do, but I don't necessarily want to help you alleviate it_. **Schadenfreude**: _I see your pain and it gives me great pleasure. Is there anything I can do to increase it?_