# Synonyms, Antonyms, and "Neutralnyms"

Tags: word-choice, synonyms, antonyms

Two words A and B are synonyms if they mean the same thing, and antonyms if they mean opposite things. But is there **a word to describe the relationship where A means "neither B nor its opposite"**?

> For example: "Indifference" means "neither love nor hate".

I would like to be able to use it in sentences of the form:
"What is a `neutralnym' for love?"

(The wikipedia page for the [-onym suffix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/-onym) says that "anonym" is already taken, sadly, as this would have been a good neologism. That's why I used "neutralnyms" even though it mixes Latin and Greek roots.)

**Edit:** A further more example to illustrate what I am asking.

> right and wrong are antonyms, and ambiguous is a neutralnym of both.

Comment: *Chliaronym* might work. χλιαρός = tepid.

Comment: What purpose would the word serve? All it'd do is tell the reader/listener that A was neither an antonym nor a synonym of B but that it was totally unrelated. Saying that "'Indifference' means 'neither love nor hate'" is so much clearer than "'Indifference' is a 'neutralnym' (or 'othernym') of 'love & hate'". Calling one word a _synonym_ of another means that it's "another name (word)" for the same meaning; calling it an _antonym_ means that it's "another name (word)" for the opposite meaning: semantically related words. "Neutralnym" is an unneeded absurdity.

Comment: Aren't all words (except for _hate_ and its synonyms) _neutralnyms_ for _love_ in your example?

Comment: I'm afraid you have taken the wrong path here. The idea you started with is not relevant to the idea of a "neutralnym," (which would be 'neither means-the-same nor means-the-opposite', => 'means something else altogether not relevant' e.g. *love* & *water*; *smart* & *java* ... Approach the issue from a new perspective. A very good question, though. @SmokerAtStadium has put it succinctly.

Comment: @SmokerAtStadium +1 Right. More like except *love* and all its synonyms and antonyms. However, that's not the question.

Comment: Linguistically speaking, I don't think there's a neutral-axis on the two sides of which lie the antonyms & synonyms. It's not that cut-and-dried. Just an aside.

Comment: @Kris and SmokerAtStadium, I think you've switched my quantifiers around a bit. It isn't 'neither (means same) nor (means opposite)', but rather 'means (neither same nor opposite)'. The first version would logically include any number of irrelevant things. But no one would say that "Water means neither love nor hate".

Comment: Water *does* mean neither love nor hate. :)  But I get your point alright:  "I don't think there's a neutral-axis on the two sides of which lie the antonyms & synonyms."

Comment: Note also that I commented to Smoker already: "However, that's not the question."

Comment: To put it another way, a word and its antonym define two antipodes, and if you interpolate between them, then a 'neutralnym' is a word that's right in the middle. Another example: _right_ and _wrong_ are antonyms, and _ambiguous_ is a neutralnym of both. While _water_ is neither right nor wrong, it certainly isn't a neutralnym of either.

Comment: If you're looking for sthg "right in a middle"  why not use either EQUIONYM (as in equidistant) or MEDIONYM (latin root medi -"middle" as in median or medieval).
As synonym is "from Latin synonymum, from Greek synōnymon"[WEBSTER] and antonym is a 1870 neologism, it sounds etymologically allright to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Word pairs like *love and hate, right and wrong* are [gradable antonyms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opposite_%28semantics%29):

> A gradable antonym is one of a pair of words with opposite meanings where the two meanings lie on a continuous spectrum. Temperature is such a continuous spectrum so hot and cold, two meanings on opposite ends of the spectrum, are gradable antonyms. Other examples include: heavy, light; fat, skinny; dark, light; young, old; early, late; empty, full; dull, interesting.

The words you're looking for are midway along the spectrum between gradable antonyms, so **medionym** would be a good neologism. However, there's another way of looking at this.

*Love* (in the sense of [*passion*](http://thesaurus.com/browse/passion) or [*ambition*](http://thesaurus.com/browse/ambition)) is also the opposite of *indifference* – just in a different direction from the *love–hate* spectrum. Likewise for *right* and *ambiguous.* The words you're talking about are still antonyms, of a special sort that is opposite to both ends of a spectrum. A good name for this would be **orthogonal antonym,** to reflect that it is “perpendicular” to gradable antonyms.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of _medionym_ (also suggested by Jo Bedard above) and for the clarification that this would only apply to gradable antonyms. I still wonder if there is an already existing word to describe this concept.

Comment: @SteveFlammia Yes, thanks to Jo Bedard! I was primarily thinking along the _orthogonal antonym_ line, but I realized that _medionym_ was an equally good way of thinking of it. I'm not aware of any existing word, other than _antonym_ (just in a different direction).

Answer (score 0):

What about trigonal antonym? Trigonyms? (such that there are three relationships interfacing, each of which is on an individually gradeable spectrum) So, instead of defining the relationship as perpendicular, each scales between the three equidistant points...for the record I also fully approve of the medionym concept! There is merit to the orthogonal antonym concept, just expanding the conversation in a slightly different direction :)