# Is this "over-negation" a grammatical phenomenon or pure coincidence?

Tags: terminology, antonyms, prefixes

To make things short, let's look at

> famous -- infamous,   glorious -- inglorious

The two pairs both illustrate what I temporarily refer to as "over-negation", in the sense that, for example, in the case of "normal" negation, *infamous* would mean *little-known* instead of *notorious* which is somewhat much stronger than just negating the original word *famous*. Same with the pair *glorious-inglorious*.

Is such "over-negation" a real grammatical phenomenon or simply coincidence? And if it's really more than coincidence, what's the proper terminology to refer to such a phenomenon?

Comment: What does the Online Etymology Dictionary say about the origins of the English words 'infamy' and 'inglorious'?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth all right. I come to realise there's another word *unfamous* which seems to be the "exact negation" of *famous*, but things are completely different when we change the prefix to *in*. But that's still strange because, as is shown in the dictionary, *in* still means nothing more than *without*.

Comment: 'The dictionary'? [At least] one of the other dictionaries {[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/in-)} is more accurate: <<in- [sense 3]
1. a prefix of Latin origin, corresponding to English un-, having a negative or privative force....>> Etymon says that _infamy_ arrived directly from Latin infamia "ill fame, bad repute, dishonor" and so in- already carried the negative rather than or in addition to the privative force in at least some Latin words. It also has <<inglorious 
"with bad fame, dishonorable," ... from in- (1) "not, opposite of" >>, again  showing the negative force.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I think Vim is interested in the phaenomenon in general, not only in the development of a specific negation; and I think there is more to it than this.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I see. Now tracing back on my thoughts motivating this question, I feel there's a subtle cultural difference between English and the language I speak. For instance in English perhaps *famous* connotes *good reputation*, and hence it's not surprising to see *infamous* as (at least one of its antonyms); in my language though, the standard translation of *famous* is somewhat a neutral word which only means *well-known*, whether the reputation is good or bad.

Comment: I don't think I ever managed to convince my father that the 'para-' in parasol was the 'against / countering' version rather than the 'in conjunction with, accompanying ... with ... for' sense. Prefixes often convey various senses. And English usage is often illogical (at least to all except the deepest of analyses, often lacking in certainty) and thus unpredictable. A scheme of work is a fine idea, but a schemer is never appreciated.

Comment: @Cerberus Your answer is good and useful, but is to the question '[Assuming the privative usage came first], how did the prefix in- in say 'infamous' come to have a negative force, when it usually/often has a privative force (as in 'insoluble, inexpert, inexact, inactive)? And OP needs more evidence of research (showing that there are differing meanings).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a good question. What you discribe is a common phaenomenon, at least in Indo-European languages. Consider how the words *immoral* and *amoral* have arbitrarily divided the two possible meanings of "not moral" between them. Compare also *inordinate* and *unordered*. The issue here is that it is often not unambiguously clear what comprises the negation or opposite of a concept. The prefix *in-* creates a word that negates or opposes the original word. But what does negation entail exactly?

Suppose you had a collection of two concepts: hot and cold. Then *uncold* means it must be hot.

But, if you are aware of the concepts "hot, lukewarm, neutral, cool, cold", then *uncold* could mean "hot, lukewarm, neutral, or cool", or it could mean "hot": it depends on your interpretation of what the available options are, and on what the opposite of *cold* is. If I replace *uncold* with *not cold*, then you are probably even less likely to think it must mean "hot".

Hot and cold are relatively simple concepts that have clear opposites. What if I say *not men*, without specifying what collection you should pick from? Does that mean "children"? Or "women"? Or "gods"?

In order to interpret "not x" or "the opposite of x", you need context, a frame of reference. Sometimes the possible interpretations are artificially divided between different suffixes, such as *un-, in-,* and *a-*. See also this question:

[**What types of antonyms are there?**](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/87264/3036)